# How to express "brewing coffee" in CV interests?

Tags: vocabulary, expression-choice

I'm not a professional barista but I have a hobby connected with brewing espresso and making all kinds of coffee. I'm also interested in various coffee beans, espresso machines etc. How to express it in CV's interests?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about personal quirks, not language.

Answer (score 1):

I would say:

- *Amongst other pursuits I am a serious coffee aficionado.*

Probably a bit too pretentious would be:

- *I am a serious coffee decoction aficionado.*

Or alternatively, also a tad pretentious:

- *I am considered by my friends to be a member of the coffee cognoscenti*.

Personally, I would go with the first option!

Comment: You're missing an "a" in the first example.

Comment: Stupid question, but does "coffee aficionado" really mean someone who knows about _brewing_ coffee implicitly?

Comment: @MrLister No, not a stupid question at all! It doesn't imply that at all by any means. The second option does, but as I mention, that option sounds a little bit affected to say the least! My answer is meant to be a little help though in the absence of any others, and maybe some moral support!.